# R version 3.1.2 on Windows 7 install.packages("devtools") fail

Tags: r, rstudio

I am unable to install devtools package using RStudio on Windows7 with errors below[*].
Appreciated in advance for any help suggestions.

```
> install.packages("devtools")
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to resolve 'cran.rstudio.com'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to resolve 'cran.rstudio.com'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Lucy/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to resolve 'cran.rstudio.com'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to resolve 'cran.rstudio.com'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘devtools’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)
```

Comment: You should try another repository.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! how to try another repository?

Comment: So this isn't really an R question but rather only an RStudio question.

Comment: You have to search in the Global Options of RStudio. Or use your favorite web search engine to find how to change the default repository in RStudio.

Comment: Use `chooseCRANmirror()` and select a new mirror near you. The RStudio CRAN mirrors were down for a short while (DNS outage)

Comment: Hi all, Thank you so much for all your comments here. This problem has been resolved. It looks like the RStudio mirror was down last time when I was trying to install it. Now, the devtool is installed  successfully.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the RStudio mirror might have been down for repairs.

[image]

The Global options choice off the Tools menu gives you several choices for panels. I brought up the list of mirror names by clicking the "Change ..." button. Some mirrors are more up-to-date and reliable than others. And pretty much all mirrors have some down time associated with their operation, and it's easy enough to try another one when your default choice is unresponsive.

[image]

You can use that to choose a different mirror.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice! Yes, you are correct. The RStudio mirror was down, and not it is up. I tried to install the devtools package again, and it succeeds now!